# Calculating Solar eclipse magnitude with the besselian elements

Tags: solar-eclipse

Calculating Solar eclipse magnitude with the besselian elements
What is the mathematic formula for calculating the magnitude of a solar eclipse using Besselian elements?
[image: Besselian elements for the June 21 2020 Annular Solar Eclipse]

Comment: Could you describe what is in the image ? Perhaps give a link to the website ?

Comment: http://xjubier.free.fr/en/site_pages/SolarEclipseCalc_Diagram.html

this is the link to another website, but I want to understand how this specific calculation is done. Apparently the details on the use of Besselian elements for the calculation is given in the Astronomical Almanac, but I'm not sure where I can find a copy of that.

The picture in the question is a table of the Besselian elements for the eclipse that occured on June 21, 2020.

Comment: Full details in: Explanatory supplement to the astronomical ephemeris and nautical almanac

Comment: I think this is good information, but an answer should be more than just a reference to an external ressource. Can you give an abridged summary? The comment clearly says the author has not access to that referenced ressource.